# Ansible WHEN with variable interpolation

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

From what I was able o find online, Ansible doesn't support varibale intrepolation very well when it comes to jinja templates.

However I'm sure that someone more advanced in Ansible has found a workaround for my problem below.

I would like to "interpolate" a variable to **WHEN** statment.
i.e. `when: Disabled in (smart_link_status.results[item[0]].stdout)`

This is my play:

```
    - name: "Get Smart Link status"
      shell: "{{ssh_command}} show network {{network_name}}_{{item}} | grep 'Smart Link'"
      register: "smart_link_status"
      with_items:
       - "{{uplink_id}}"

   - name: "enable SmartLink for the network"
     shell: "{{ssh_command}} set network {{network_name}}_{{item[1]}} SmartLink={{smart_link}}"
     when: Disabled in (smart_link_status.results[item[0]].stdout)
     with_indexed_items:
       - "{{uplink_id}}"
```

How can I achieve this? Seem's that I can do it easly with normal modules i.e. **debug** but not with the **WHEN** statement.

This works fine:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ls_bin.results[item[0]].stdout}}"
  with_indexed_items:
    - "{{bob}}"
```

Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you paste the error message? I guess _Disabled_ is a string and should be quoted.

Comment: THANKS! That was one of the problems, The seond issue was I was running ansible-play with `--start-at-task` and skipping the task for creating the `smart_link_status` in the first place. (face_palm)

Comment: "Conditionals" Ansible documentation mentions a few examples of "when" with filters, I think this might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The here were two issues:

- One of the as correctly pointed by @Konstantin Suvorov was that I did not use the quotation.
- The other problem was that I was running the ansible-playbook with `--start-at-task` and thus skipping the step where `smart_link_status` was created.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    when: smart_link_status is defined and smart_link_status.results[item[0]].stdout.find('Disabled') != -1
```

Also, in the `shell` task, I would use `check_mode: no` so that `smart_link_status` will be undefined when running in check mode.  Otherwise, you'll get errors on the subsequent access to `smart_link_status.results`.